# How to get the Bootstrap gap to work on a mobile device

Tags: android, bootstrap-5

I'm working on a web application that uses Bootstrap 5.0 for the styling and I have a strange anomaly going on.

I have a collection of buttons (`<a>...</a>`) that are lined up in a horizontal pattern as shown in the attached image. As you can see, the desktop view looks great, but for some reason, looking at this on my mobile phone, the buttons are all crunched together indicating that the gap part of the `class="d-grid gap-2 d-sm-flex"` is being ignored by my mobile phone.

In my dev environment, I use the browser's dev tools (F12) to view it using Galaxy S5 in landscape mode which is the closest thing to my Galaxy A51 5G phone. My immediate suspicion is that perhaps it has to do with the fact that the gap-# in bootstrap translates to **rem** rather than **pixels**. I'm looking into that now. Until then please let me know if you have a more concrete answer.

Thanks a bunch.

[image: Desktop vs. Mobile view of buttons]

Okay, I found an acceptable workaround, but I'm still interested if you know what the deal is with the `gap-#` not working on the mobile device. Here's what I did for now...

I removed all of the `class="gap-#"` and placed the following in the class of each button inside the foreach loop that places the buttons:

`<button class="mb-2 mb-sm-0 me-0 me-sm-2" type="button" ... </button>`.

This allows me to set the bottom margin of each button to have some space with the right side having no space while in mobile (portrait mode), but then have the bottom margins set to 0 and the right (end) margins set to have some space while in landscape mode and every size larger than the smallest size.

It seems a bit "hacky", but it works.

Please answer if you know a better way to get the `gap-#` to work in landscape mode of a small mobile device.

Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I tried the idea of changing rem to pixels but that still didn't do the trick. Again, it looks great on the desktop but there are no spaces between the buttons on the mobile view in landscape mode. Still crackin' away at it.

Comment: It most likely has something to do with the browser's support for `display:grid`

Comment: I was thinking about that @zim and it may well be. I tested it using the Edge browser on the desktop as well as others and they all worked out fine. However, when I view it with the Edge browser on my phone, that's where I get the issue. I have not tested it on any other phone browsers. I suppose I should. Thanks for the input.